# Adding paths to arguments in popen

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I want to execute a Linux command through Python. This works in the terminal:

`/usr/bin/myprogram --path "/home/myuser"`

I've tried this:

```
path = "/home/myuser"
args = ['/usr/bin/myprogram', '--path ' + path]
proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

And this:

```
path = "/home/myuser"
args = ['/usr/bin/myprogram', '--path "' + path + '"']
proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

But `myprogram` does not accept the path formatting. I know that paths behave differently when not executing as shell but I can't get it working. I've also tried single quoting the path instead of double quoting it. Bonus points for a solution that also works on Windows (with a different program path, obviously).

EDIT: Sorry, was writing this out from memory and used backslashes instead of forward slashes. The actual code did use the (correct) forward slashes.

Comment: Have you tried `args = ['\usr\bin\myprogram', '--path', path]`? I've used that construction previously with success, albeit on Windows. EDIT - you might also need to escape your backslashes using `\\`

Comment: try `subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/myprogram --path "/home/myuser"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()`

Comment: Why don't you just use `['/usr/bin/myprogram', '--path' , path]`?

Comment: @asongtoruin Your solution works on Linux, if I use forward slashes! If I'm lucky it'll work on Windows too without escaping the backslashes.

Comment: @tsorn, what do you mean *without escaping the backslashes*? You don't need to escape anything if you use `/`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know if it's the correct word for it, but using \\ to represent a backslash as mentioned in another solution

Comment: @tsorn, just use forward slashes on linux and windows. You should never be using backslashes on liunux.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's user input, so I guess I'll have to replace backslashes with forward slashes on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("/usr/bin/myprogram --path /home/myuser")
```

Mind the forward slashes ("/"). From what I read, Python doesn't like backslashes ("\") even when running on Windows (I've never used it on Windows myself).

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from your string literal, `'\usr\bin\myprogram'`. According to [escaping rules](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), `\b` is replaced by `\x08`, so your executable is not found.

Pun an `r` in front of your string literals (i.e. `r'\usr\bin\myprogram'`), or use `\\` to represent a backslash (i.e. `'\\usr\\bin\\myprogram'`).